# enable ?year=2016 (future) to Wordpress query string to list next years posts

Tags: wordpress

I have written an events plugin that displays posts that are set in the future.

Im generating links that when clicked they lead to a list of posts grouped by month and year.
This is an example of a permalink,this query string displays all the post for May 2015
events-diary/?year=2015-05
this query string displays all the post for June 2015

events-diary/?year=2015-06
 events-diary/?year=2015-07  displays all the post for July 2015 and so on.

The problem is when I try to query next years posts it leads to a 404 page. It seems that there is some kind of security feature that prevents people querying lists of posts dated in future years. Which is weird because the individual posts for next year work fine. e.g 
 this query string works fine. events/post-name-of-2016-post/
Is there a work around for this url restriction?

```
       $loop = new WP_Query(
       array(
       'post_type' => 'future_events',
       'orderby' => 'date',
       'order' => 'ASC'
        //  'post_status' => 'future'
           )
         );



      if ($loop->have_posts()){
      $dates = array();  
      while ($loop->have_posts()) {
        # code...
      $loop->the_post();
      $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'');
      $object = get_post();
        //print_r($object) ;
      $dates[] = substr($object->post_date, 0 ,-12) ;

      }
      $vals = array_count_values($dates);
     //print_r($vals);
     foreach ($vals as $key => $value) {
     # code...
    $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
    $date = date_create($key.'-'.$value.'-00');
    $output2 .= '<a href="'. site_url().'/'.  
     get_query_var('pagename').'/?year='.$key .'">'. 
     date_format($date, 'M Y').' ('.$value .') </a><br> ' ; //.
     <br>';

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, the date of a post is set then the post is created. So you cannot have posts created in the future.

You can do what you want by having a custom meta value which is the actual event date, and basing your query on meta_key/meta_value.

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
   array(
   'post_type' => 'future_events',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_key' => 'my_date',
   'meta_value' => $_GET['myyear']
    //  'post_status' => 'future'
       )
     );
```

Comment: I am showing future posts by running a custom database query that updates all future posts to 'published' if the custom post type is 'future_event'. I might have to do it your way but I would like to know why it blocked future years in the query string but not  future months for this year..

Comment: I suspect that it is for the reason I stated - you cannot have a post creation **year** in the future, so it is preventing an error. Any month is valid.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to disable this functionality of preventing next years posts being disabled in the post listings, it must be possible because the single posts themselves are perfectly viewable, even if they are dated for years in the future...